# Configuration verification

Tags: bash, perl

- `ssh` to an IP supplied via user input
- Inject `show running-config` command
- Search the output of the command and look for specific parameters like ports, QoS, VTY lines, SMTP settings, IP helpers etc.
- Output only if the predefined parameters are not in place

If I store the output of the `ssh` run in a variable, is there a method I can use for parsing through it and just go with endless `if`, `elsif`, and `else` statements? How would that look?

It can be in Python bash or Perl, doesn't matter to me really but I don't know how to structure the thing and then fill in the gaps and expand the script.

Here's where I imagine starting from

```
use Net::SSH2 
use File::Slurp;

print "\nEnter command list filename: "; 
my $commandlist = <STDIN>; 
chomp($commandlist);

my @commandfile = read_file($commandlist, chomp => 1); 
my $commandsize = @commandfile;
```

How would I store the output of the commands in a variable or a temporary file and parse through it with conditions?

Comment: What is the purpose of the command list file?

Comment: To have a set of commands for each category - routers checks , switch checks , WLC checks etc . This was my first thought - to go with external command list .

Comment: `File::Slurp` has issues and [should be avoided](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html), btw. Alternatives include [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) (Or in this case just reading the file a line at a time like normal)

Comment: The [documentation for open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) has examples for how to capture the output from running a program.

Comment: "sh running-config " is a command displaying the full host configuration . It provides a very long output of the different settings and parameters of a device. My question is how do I set a parser to go over this output and search for some key elements of interest ?

Comment: Here is the login in my "start"

print "\nEnter switch list filenane: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;                        
chomp($input);
my @hostfile = read_file($input,chomp => 1);       
my $arrSize = @hostfile;
my $user = "username"; 
print "\nEnter ssh password: ";
my $password = <STDIN>;       
chomp($password);
print "\nEnter enable password: ";
my $secret = <STDIN>;   
chomp($secret);

Comment: "*How would I [...] parse through [text] with conditions?*" is super vague. There are multiple decades of research into parser theory. Without a concrete problem to solve, I vote to close this question as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, and it is unclear exactly what is puzzling you

The documentation for
[`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2)
and
[`Net::SSH2::Channel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Channel)
describes clearly how to open a *channel*, send commands to it, and receive the response

You ask how you could store the results of the command in a variable, but it would be very awkward to do anything else. Again, the documentation describes this clearly

I suggest that you try writing some working code and experiment with it. It will be much easier to help you when you have a *specific* question